# error in accessing struct with arrays as properties

Tags: arrays, struct, swift4

I am trying to access a array of structs using properties get/set
Each TransactionRecord Struct has location and for each location there is array of transactions. Each transaction is of type TransactionRecord

Here is my code:

```
struct TransactionRecord {
    var transactionId: String
    var transactionType: String
}

struct TransactionPackage{
    var location: String
    var transactions: [TransactionRecord]
}
var data = TransactionPackage(location: "", transactions: []) {
        didSet {
            if oldValue == nil || data == nil {
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    var transaction: TransactionPackage {
        get {
            var transactions = [TransactionRecord]()
            if data.transactions.count > 1 {
                for transaction in data.transactions.last ?? [TransactionRecord]  {
                     transactions.append(transaction)
                }
            }
            return TransactionPackage(location: data.location, transactions: transactions)
        }
        set {
           data = [[newValue.location], newValue.transactions]
        }
    }
```

I am getting multiple errors:
on line: 
for transaction in data.transactions.last ?? [TransactionRecord]  {
I get error:
Cannot convert value of type '[TransactionRecord].Type' to expected argument type 'TransactionRecord'

on the line:
data = [[newValue.location], newValue.transactions ]
I get error:
Cannot assign value of type '[Any]' to type 'TransactionPackage'

Can I get some help?

Comment: What is the line `for transaction in data.transactions.last ?? [TransactionRecord]  {` supposed to do?

Comment: I am hoping to get the TransactionRecord element from the array of TransactionRecords sequentially and then append it to another array and use that to instantiate the transaction package

Comment: If I remove the default portion ?? [TransactionRecord], then I get error: Type 'TransactionRecord?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Comment: var data = [TransactionPackage(location: "", transactions: [])] {
didSet {
if oldValue == nil || data == nil {
tableView.reloadData() }}}
var transaction: TransactionPackage {
 get {
var transactions = [TransactionRecord]()
if data.count > 1 {
for transaction in data.first?.transactions.first {
 transactions.append(transaction)} }
   return TransactionPackage(location: data.first?.location ?? "", transactions: transactions)}
 set {
 data = [[newValue.location], newValue.transactions] as! [TransactionPackage]}}

Comment: With the revised code posted above that accepts, I get error: Type 'TransactionRecord?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'. I dont know which one is right?

Comment: `data = [[newValue.location], newValue.transactions] as! [TransactionPackage]` is wrong and will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error says that you are using a type `[TransactionRecord]` as default value rather than an instance of the type for example an empty array `[]`

The second error says you cannot assign `[Any]` to a value of `TransactionPackage`

I guess you want to map `data` to `transaction` as a computed property

```
var transaction: TransactionPackage {
    get {
        return TransactionPackage(location: data.location, transactions: data.transactions)
    }
    set {
       data = TransactionPackage(location: newValue.location, transactions: newValue.transactions)
    }
}
```

or much simpler

```
var transaction: TransactionPackage {
    get {
        return data
    }
    set {
       data = newValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is corrected Code.

```
    struct TransactionRecord {
        var transactionId: String
        var transactionType: String
    }

    struct TransactionPackage{
        var location: String
        var transactions = [TransactionRecord]()
    }
    var data = TransactionPackage(location: "", transactions: []) {
        didSet {
                //tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    var transaction: TransactionPackage {
        get {
            var trans = [TransactionRecord]()
            if data.transactions.count > 1 {
//Corrections 1,2
                for transaction in data.transactions ?? []  {
                    trans.append(transaction)
                }
            }
            return TransactionPackage(location: data.location, transactions: trans)
        }
        set {
//Corrections 3
            data = TransactionPackage(location: newValue.location, transactions: newValue.transactions)
        }
    }
```

Corrections

1. In For loop you must have to pass array not the last value.
2. ?? is used to provide default value.
3. data is TransactionPackage so you need to assign it as complete TransactionPackage. Or you can do like this.

> ```
> data.location = newValue.location
> data.transactions = newValue.transactions
> ```

Comment: Both answers worked for me. I selected Vadian because he answered it first, no offense to Dhruv

Comment: It's ok.
Thanks.